# Add and remove Spring Boot health checks dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I am working on a Spring Boot-based application where domain-specific tasks are added and removed dynamically via an API. As those jobs can fail individually, I would like to add `HealthIndicator`s for each job while they are running and remove them afterwards. The Spring Actuator's *health* endpoint is already integrated into several monitors and this would just push this information downstream.

I could of course aggregate the health checks of all jobs into one `HealthIndicator` bean but I would prefer if the health of all checks was listed somehow. The `HealthIndicator` does however only allow to return a single `Health` instance. Is there a way to return a collection of such objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.1 introduced a [HealthIndicatorRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicatorRegistry.html) for this purpose. Whenever the health endpoint is queried, the registry is asked for a snapshot of all registered health indicators and each of those indicators is then called to determine the application's health.

The registry is available as a bean so can be injected into your class that manages the domain-specific tasks. It could then call `register(String, HealthIndicator)` and `unregister(String)` as those tasks are added and removed.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring Boot 2.3, HealthIndicatorRegistry has been deprecated in favour of [HealthContributorRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthContributorRegistry.html).

You can use `registerContributor(String name,C contributor)` to register and `unregisterContributor(String name)` to remove which is quite similar to the previous API.

This has been available since 2.1.0